# How can I export data tab separated

Tags: laravel

I'm exporting some Data from a DB and I want to have the 2 columns that I generate Tab separated.

I've already tried to use implode after my fputcsv but it always appears comma separated. Also tried changing my separator (,) to some other character, but a comma is always printed in the CSV.

This is the function that I'm using for it.

```
public function ResearchExport(Request $request)
{
    //Export ProductID and KitID of all the Kits created from the given date to the actual moment
    $TubeAddDate = $request->input('TubeAddDate');
    $select = DB::table('tubes')->select('TubeBarcodeID', 'ActivationCode')->where('LOG_important', '2')->whereBetween('TubeAddDate', array($TubeAddDate, NOW()))->get();
    $tot_record_found=0;
    if (count($select)>0) {
        $tot_record_found=1;
        $CsvData=array('TubeBarcodeID,ActivationCode');
        foreach ($select as $value) {
            $CsvData[]=$value->TubeBarcodeID.",".$value->ActivationCode.;
        }
        $filename=date('Y-m-d').".csv"; //stores the file with the date of today as name
        $file_path=storage_path().'/'.$filename;
        $file = fopen($file_path, "w+");
        foreach ($CsvData as $exp_data) {
            fputcsv($file, explode(",", $exp_data));
        }
        fclose($file);
        return response()->download($file_path, $filename);
    }
    return view('InsertForms/download', ['record_found' =>$tot_record_found]);
}
```

At the moment I'm getting this as output

```
TubeBarcodeID,ActivationCode
FF01111112,IKG5G-B0FIZ
FF0111113,6XMP8-760Y3
```

but I expect something tab separated in the CSV like this

```
TubeBarcodeID   ActivationCode
FF01111112      IKG5G-B0FIZ
FF0111113       6XMP8-760Y3
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what a CSV is. It's a comma separated value filetype.  Which means all the data is separated by commas. You can open it up in something like Excel or Numbers to see the listed in columns.

Comment: Excel is also based on CSV. But you can open a CSV file in excel as well. 
But an hint for an alternative: Use PDO - PHP Data Base Objects. This allows you to export data from databases into an excel formatted file.

Comment: @swonder you pointed something really important that I completely missed, I actually just solved the problem.

Comment: @liqSTAR thanks for your help, I will take a look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually just solved thanks to one of the commentaries that pointed out my error.
I just had to change my .csv to .xls and then override the third parameter of fputcsv with a "\t".

```
    $filename=date('Y-m-d').".xls"; //stores the file with the date of today as name
    $file_path=storage_path().'/'.$filename;
    $file = fopen($file_path, "w+");
    foreach ($CsvData as $exp_data) {
        fputcsv($file, explode(",", $exp_data), "\t");
    }
```